# Create a Read More that slides down the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have a problem. I have the following code in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o7x14gzd/1/ for a creation of a button to read more with jquery.

```
var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;
```

It should slide down the text til the end and fade out. More information on this site: https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

I do not know where it is wrong but when the text is too big it does not show anything when you click "Read More".

Some of you already faced something like this or can tell me where is the error?

Comment: is the **max-height:9999** the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1- You have to use `outerHeight(true)` instead of `outerHeight()` to calculate the real size of Paragraphs containing **Margins**.

2- instead of calculating all heights specially if you have **list** or **images** , I suggest this method:
put the current height of parent element is a class say **startheight** and assign it to your **view**:

```
.srartheight{height:150px;}
```

to calculate the final height , use this method:

```
finalheight=$("#view").removeClass("startheight").height();
$("#view").addClass("startheight");
```